# Redirect to different template other than single-custompost.php

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

I have a custom post `portfolio` . On test page there are featured images from the custom post

When i click on the featured image a popup opens for each post and there is little description and a read more button(the_permalink())

But now i don't want it to take me to single-portfolio.php.

Rather i want it to take me to some different template like single-portfolio-custom.php

How do i acheive it . please any suggestions

Comment: Why? Why the extra complexity?

Comment: Because i was doing some tweakings for somebody in a webpaint theme .Like i mentioned above from the read more button the person will be redirected to a template where only some images and comments for the post would be there and not complete data. I may use simply the single-portfolio.php and customize it according to me but what if the person wants to also use the functionality of single-portfolio.php in future and display all the data for the portfolio

Comment: Pass a parameter through to the page when you want truncated results?